# SilverLight 4, DataGrid, DataGridColumnHeader, MouseLeftButtonDown event

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, mouseleftbuttondown, datagridcolumnheader

DataGridColumnHeader has event MouseLeftButtonDown. How can i use this event ?

How can i join DataGridColumnHeader with DataGridColumn ?

```
for Example:
...
  DataGridTextColumn TC;
  TC = new DataGridTextColumn();
  TC.Header = "ID";
  TC.Binding = new Binding();
  TC.Binding.Converter = new MyCustomConverter();
  TC.Binding.ConverterParameter = 0;

  // I need something like this:
  TC.MouseLeftButtonDown += new event .... 
  // i need - when click on column header, my custom function will executed.

  dataGrid.Columns.Add( TC );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

worst code i have ever seen;) sry
u should use a method(callback)/lambda sure satisfies an event delegate signature to handle the event

Callback approach:

```
TC.MouseLeftButtonDown += MouseLeftButtonDownHandler;
//define callback
private void MouseLeftButtonDownHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs mouseButtonEventArgs)
{
    //write ur logic here...
}
```

Lambda approach

```
TC.MouseLeftButtonDown += (sender, args) => {//write ur logic here}
//where "sender" means the object raises the event(i.e. "TC"), args - object contains some helpfull information about the happened event(like "ClickCount", etc.).
```

This links will be usefull:

[Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

[Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)